# C++ very simple thread?

Tags: c++

What is the simplest way of making a thread in c++? I want to make one that uses an already declared method to run. Something like:

```
 void task1(){
    cout << "Thread started";
 }

 thread t1 = thread(task1());
```

I guess I want to make a thread that doesn't require downloading any libraries and that my compiler will most likely be able to compile. And a big question I want answered is, what is c++11? Is it a whole different language, or a bundle of libraries?

Comment: Using what threading standard? [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)? POSIX? Win32?

Comment: You're close to the real thing: `std::thread t1(task1)`;

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, "doesn't require downloading any libraries and that my compiler will most likely be able to compile." What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, you could ask the "big question" in a different question - you will likely get more thorough answer to it.

Answer (score 7):

C++11 has thread library. A very simple example is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void task1()
{
    std::cout<<"Thread started\n";
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(task1);
    t.join();
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread

Comment: And in C++03, `boost::thread` will offer something very similar.

Comment: What is c++11, a library or a programming language?

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, it is a new standard of C++. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11. The C++ creator Bjarne Stroustrup said "it feels like a new language".

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, No,C++11 is still a language but with a lot more additional features added compared to previous C++ standards. thread is one of the libraries added into C++11 standard.

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, It's an update to the C++ language. It comes with all sorts of new language features, as well as some standard library updates. Modern C++ *is* C++11. By the way, MinGW is tricky to get `<thread>` working with. It works fine on POSIX systems, but not Windows.

Comment: Hmm. Because windows is in c++ so I thought it had all of the c++ libraries. Would you need a whole new compiler? Sorry if I'm a noob, I came from java.

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee, There's one GCC 4.7.0 (or close to that) port somewhere that has it working. Alternatively, Visual Studio 2012 has it, and the express edition is free.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use C++11, it depends upon what you are programming for. The following "simple as possible" threading example is written in unmanaged Win32 code, using the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {
    WORD numSeconds = 0;
    for (;;) {
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << numSeconds++ << " seconds elapsed in child thread!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD threadID;
    WORD numSeconds = 0;

    cout << "Hello world" << endl;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID);

    Sleep(500);
    for (;;) {
        cout << numSeconds++ << " seconds elapsed in main thread!" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you use this approach, remember that the function pointer passed to CreateThread must have the signature:

```
DWORD ThreadFuncion(LPVOID lpParameter);
```

You can find the description of that signature on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Small nitpick, though you did include it in the example: The signature of the function pointer should include that calling convention as well.

Comment: My computer couldn't compile this. Help?

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard gets revised often every  few years. Some cool things get added and old things are kept for backward compatibility. Here is some [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization).

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has a very good influence in driving the C++ standard.